# multiple mount points in same partition

Tags: lvm

If got a logic partition (LVM) with `/tmp`..

How move `/var/tmp` to the same logic partition?

So we would have `/tmp` & `var/tmp` in the same.

*(Both are Ext4, `var/tmp` is currently in `/var` partition.)*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a symlink.

```
mv /var/tmp /var/tmp.old 

ln -s /tmp /var/tmp
```

should do the trick

Comment: thx for answer. Its all? Im beginner so Im a bit lost. Also it will save and mount every boot?

Comment: Yes, that is all, and it will be save every mount. 
 
A symbolic link, I used to taught it as "a worm hole"...  you "enter" /var/tmp but in reality, you are entering /tmp  just like if you where teletransported... 
 
Before we got LVM, we used to manage the space and new disk with symbolic links.

Comment: Well, I'm isolating some mount points for security, but it seems not secure (I guess). Don't know how do it from Debian installer (LVM)

Comment: the most important part of securing a /tmp partition is to add noexec to the fstab options, that prevents from programs to be executed from the /tmp directory ...

Comment: should then noexec on /var/tmp too?

Comment: but you aren't any longermounting /var/tmp,. /var/tmp redirects to /tmp who already has noexec....